# FireDac FDQuery commit changed DataFields when browsing through results

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have a FDQuery bound to a FDConnection.

I am displaying the data on my form with DB Data-Aware components.

Whenever i use the FPQuery.Next, .Prior, ... it browses between the results.

Everything is working fine.

Except when i change a value (e.g. John -> Jane) and then use FPQuery.Next to get the next result it saves commits the changed value to the db even tho i didn't FDQuery1.CommitUpdates.

Is there a way to only save changed DataFields when the user presses the nbPost-Button or uses FDQuery1.CommitUpdates and NOT when browsing between results?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: By default, Delphi TDataSets post any changes to the current row before moving the dataset cursor to another row, as with .Next or .Prior.  The standard TDBNavigator Post button only calls DataSet.Post and does not, by itself commit changes to the back-end DB.  Are you looking to defer committing changes or cancelling them before the dataset scrolls?  In other words, how do you want your app to respond when the user scrolls away from a row with unsaved/uncommitted changes?

Comment: Thanks MartynA. I want to discard unsaved/uncommited changes when the user scrolls to the next / prior data. I only want to save them when the user presses the green tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in a comment, the standard `TDataset` behaviour is to call its `.Post` method to save changes to the current row before navigating to another one.  This happens in the routine `TDataSet.CheckBrowseMode` in `Data.DB.Pas`, which is called before any navigation action.  This can't be changed without deriving a custom `TDataset` descendant.

(from Data.DB.Pas)

```
procedure TDataSet.CheckBrowseMode;
begin
  CheckActive;
  DataEvent(deCheckBrowseMode, 0);
  case State of
    dsEdit, dsInsert:
      begin
        UpdateRecord;
        if Modified then Post else Cancel;
      end;
    dsSetKey:
      Post;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, a `TDataSet` has a `BeforePost` event, so it might be tempting to try and use that to cancel changes;  however, the problem with `BeforePost` is how to determine the context in which it is being called, so as to be able to tell whether its being called from `CheckBrowseMode` rather than as a result of the user clicking the Save button.

The simple way around that is to catch the `BeforeAction` event of your `DBNavigator`, before it calls a navigation action on the dataset which will trigger the `.Post`:

```
procedure TForm1.DBNavigator1BeforeAction(Sender: TObject; Button:
    TNavigateBtn);
var
  Res : Integer;
  DataSet : TDataSet;
begin
  DataSet := DBNavigator1.DataSource.DataSet;
  case Button of
    nbFirst,
    nbPrior,
    nbNext,
    nbLast: begin
      if DataSet.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then begin
        Res := MessageDlg('The current row has unsaved changes.  Abandon them?', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0);
        if Res = mrYes then
          DataSet.Cancel
        else
          DataSet.Post;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answer MartynA.

If you do not want to limit on navigator component and have such a check in general you can override TFDQuery.InternalPost like so:

```
procedure TFDQuery.InternalPost;
begin
  if State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
  begin
    if MessageDlg('Save changes?', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
      Cancel();
  end;

  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my answer, the problem with a "catch-all" check is determining the context in which the check is being called.  I think a user would be entitled to be irritated if every time they do an explicit save (e.g. by clicking the DNav's Save button), they get asked for confirmation.  Anyway, the OP has obviously got the idea about posting happening automatically unless you take steps to avoid it.